# Bird identification: Warora, India

Tags: species-identification, taxonomy, ornithology

[image: A bird with vertically elongated body, perched upright, moderately long beak]
[image: The bird now extended its neck taking a gopher like stance]
[image: The same bird having white ventral surface and soiled brown back, back to its resting position]

These photographs have been taken in Warora, India. Could someone please help identify this bird?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [pond heron or paddy bird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Pond_Heron). The de-facto source for identifying Indian birds is [Birds of the Indian Subcontinent](http://www.flipkart.com/birds-indian-subcontinent-2nd/p/itmczyt8ck3x2ape) by Richard Grimmett, Carol Inskipp and Tim Inskipp. The book is remarkably complete and contains the vast majority of species found in the Indian Subcontinent.

[image]